# Login sem selecionar nível

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo um site em PHP para meu TCC, e uma das orientações dadas era para que fosse retirada a seleção de nível, e que isso fosse feito automaticamente pelo sistema. Minha professora disse que era só retirar o código de selecionar, mas se eu faço isso nada acontece. Segue abaixo os códigos HTML e PHP

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="php/usuarioautenticado.php">

            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required="required" placeholder="Usuário"/>

            <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" required="required" placeholder="Senha"/>

            <select name="nivel" form="form2" class="select">
                <option value="">Escolha seu nível</option>
                <option value="admin">Administrador</option>
                <option value="usuario">Usuário</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
```

```
<?php // Código para verificação no banco do login e senha
   if (isset ($_POST ['enviar'])){// se o campo enter for clicado

       $username=$_POST['username'];
       $senha=$_POST['senha'];
       $nivel=$_POST['nivel'];

       $query = @mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE username='$username' AND senha ='$senha' AND nivel='$nivel'"); // Verifique no banco se o login e a senha digitados existem.
       $conta = @mysql_num_rows ($query);// conte os dados do banco selecionados na variável query

       if ($conta == '0') {// se o valor digitado não existir 

            echo "<script language= 'javascript'> window.alert('Os campos  não correspondem');</script>"; 

            header ("LOCATION: ../index.php");


        }else{

            while ($resultado= @mysql_fetch_array($query) ){// estamos verificando os dados do banco em uma lista ( array )

        $id = $resultado ['id']; 
        $username= $resultado ['username'];
        $senha = $resultado ['senha'];
        $nivel = $resultado ['nivel'];

       // vamos abrir a sessão pois para que possamos manipular páginas com nivel é preciso abrir a sessão para manter os dados abertos e também deve ter um botão de sair para destruir a sessão. 

       session_start ();
       $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
       $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel;

       // redirecionar para página correta

       if ($nivel == 'admin'){ 

     header ("LOCATION: select.php");

       }elseif ($nivel =='usuario'){

     header ("LOCATION: mostradados.php");

       }else{

        return false;

       }

        }}
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: Já tentou remover o ` AND nivel='$nivel'` na *query*?

Comment: Sim, tentei umas 2 vezes e não foi.

Comment: Clica em **[edit]** e posta como você está fazendo atualmente.

Comment: Como assim? Desculpa, sou nova aqui, não sei muito bem como o site funciona :/

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você está usando 2 usuários iguais com perfils diferentes?
Segue como faço logins nos meus sistemas:

**Tabela**

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIO -- CADASTRO: SU
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
EMAIL VARCHAR(100),
SENHA VARCHAR(100),
STATU INT, -- ATIVO / INATIVO
ACESSO VARCHAR(3), -- PRO, CAX, USU
SUU INT, -- SUPER USUARIO
DATA_CADASTRO DATETIME,
DATE_UPDATE DATETIME
);
```

**Form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal m-t-20" id="loginform" method="post">
                    <div class="row p-b-30">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text bg-success text-white" id="basic-addon1"><i class="ti-user"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="email" name="txtEmail" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text bg-warning text-white" id="basic-addon2"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="password" name="txtSenha" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Senha" aria-label="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row border-top border-secondary">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="p-t-20">
                                <br>
                                    <button class="btn btn-info" id="to-recover" type="button"><i class="fa fa-lock m-r-5"></i> Esqueceu a Senha?</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-success float-right" name="btnEntrar" type="submit">Entrar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**Post na página**

```
if (isset($_POST["btnEntrar"])) {
                                echo "<script>document.getElementById('btnEntrar').disabled=true;</script>";
                                if (!isset($_SESSION["NUMTENTATIVAS"])) {
                                    $_SESSION["NUMTENTATIVAS"] = 0;
                                }
                                if ($_SESSION["NUMTENTATIVAS"] >= 5) {
                                    echo "<script>document.getElementById('btnEntrar').disabled=false;</script>";
                                    echo "<script> $(function(){
        toastr.warning('Você está temporariamente bloqueado, aguarde alguns minutos e tente novamente ou clique em Esqueceu a Senha para enviar um email!', 'Atenção!');
    });
            </script>";
                                } else {
                                    require_once 'DAO/UsuarioDAO.php';
                                    $u = new UsuarioDAO();
                                    $u->EMAIL = trim($_POST["txtEmail"]);
                                    $u->SENHA = md5($_POST["txtSenha"]);
                                    $msg = $u->EfetuarLogin();
                                    if($msg == "OK") {
                                        echo "<script> $(function(){
        toastr.success('Carregando...', 'Sucesso!');
    });
            </script>";
                                        $_SESSION["EMAIL"] = $u->EMAIL;
                                        $_SESSION["ID"] = $u->ID;
                                        $_SESSION["TIPO"] = $u->ACESSO;
                                        $_SESSION["SU"] = $u->SUU;

                                        LogDAO::InsertLog("Login", "Entrou", "Entrou no Sistema", $_SESSION["EMAIL"], __ROOT__."/web");
                                        echo "<script>location.href='".$link."/Painel';</script>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<script>document.getElementById('btnEntrar').disabled=false;</script>";
                                        $erro = true;
                                    }
                                        if($erro){
                                            $_SESSION["NUMTENTATIVAS"] = $_SESSION["NUMTENTATIVAS"] + 1;
                                            LogDAO::InsertLog("Login", "Erro", "Tentativa ".$_SESSION["NUMTENTATIVAS"]." de Login - ".$msg, $u->EMAIL, __ROOT__."/web");
                                            echo "<script> $(function(){
        toastr.error('".$msg."', 'Erro!');
    });
            </script>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

**Classe UsuarioDAO**

```
function EfetuarLogin(){
    $this->ErroCode = 0;
    $this->ErroMsg = "";
    require_once "Conexao/conexao.php";
    $c = new conexao();
    try{
        $c->Abrir();
        $SQL = "SELECT ID, STATU, ACESSO, SUU FROM USUARIO WHERE EMAIL = '".$this->EMAIL."' AND SENHA = '".$this->SENHA."'";
        $c->ExecQuery($SQL);
        while($eqp = $c->FetchArray()){
            $this->ErroCode = 0;
            $this->ErroMsg = "OK!";
            $this->ID = $eqp["ID"];
            $this->ACESSO = $eqp["ACESSO"];
            $this->SUU = $eqp["SUU"];

            if($eqp["STATU"] == 0) {
                $this->ErroCode = 1;
                $this->ErroMsg = "Usuário Inativo!";
            }
        }

        if($this->ErroMsg == ""){
            $this->ErroMsg = "Email ou Senha Incorretos!";
        }

        if($this->ErroMsg == "OK!"){
            return "OK";
        } else {
            return $this->ErroMsg;
        }
    }catch (Exception $e){
        $this->ErroCode = 1;
        $this->ErroMsg = "Erro ao Efetuar Login - ".$e->getMessage();
        return $this->ErroMsg;
    }//finally{
    $c->Fechar();
    //}
}
```

Eu também crio uma tela para gerenciamento dos usuários onde o administrador pode trocar o acesso de cada um.
Espero que ajude :)